# Optimal way to make live data chart with windows forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to create a live data chart. I am getting information from serial port, and I need to graph some values to a chart. For now I am parsing data on another thread to table and every 100ms update chart with calling from timer chart.DataBind();. This solution seems to "work", but it looks laggy after few thousand points. So my question is, what is the optimal way to create live data charts?

Comment: Isn´t "optimal" already a superlative? Making "most optimal" said twice? Anyway: there is no "best" or "optimal" unless you describe what measuremtn counts for you: performance? memory allocation? usability? Lines of code? You have to be far more specific on what you´re doing, your data and **what you´ve tried already**.

Comment: youve implied as it slows with more points that you are recalculating all the data.. then you need to work out a way to effect the differences the new data makes on the original value

Comment: User doesn't have to see every single point for large sets. They just need the gist of it. So either show them a "simplified" view of the chart or let them pick a region of the chart that they are interested in.

Comment: *Most optimal* is too broad. But if you are looking for a few solutions, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40415298/3110834), one of the answers have shared an example of livecharts, another one shared mschart.

Comment: Then you can compare their performance.